# YOLOv8 output format after conversion to ONNX

Tags: pytorch, onnx, yolov8

I converted YOLOv8 detection (specifically best.pt checkpoint) model to onnx formate but i dont know how to get bounding boxes and confidence from it. And i also dont know if model was converted correctly.

Shape that i was expecting was something like |1, 25200, 7| where last number is x,y,w,h,confidence, class0, class1. Instead i got |1, 5, 5040| which i dont know if it is correct and just transposed and 7 instead of 5 because i have only one class, or if it is compleatly wrong and i messed up while converting i tryed 2 types of convertion

```
    import torch
    import torchvision
    import torch.onnx
    from ultralytics import YOLO
    from torchsummary import summary
    
    m = YOLO("best.pt")
    m.model.eval()
    
    dummy_input = torch.randn(1, 3, 384, 640)
    
    #first way of convertion
    m.export(format="onnx",imgsz=[384,640], opset=12)
    
    #second way of coversion
    torch.onnx.export(m.model, dummy_input, "yolo5.onnx", verbose=True, opset_version=12)
```

i both cases i got output shape: |1, 5, 5040|
This is netron image of model [model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHwCI.jpg)
[summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9Wgq.png)
Is this right, just transposing it  does not feel right
What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your description misses the question. I assume, you want to understand the output format of the Yolov8 ONNX converted model and how to use it in your code. I'll pick a C++ implementation for the answer since you haven't mentioned the programming language you're writing in either.

There are two alternatives:

1. Take a look at https://github.com/mallumoSK/yolov8/blob/master/yolo/YoloDet.cpp. The `detect` function implements the logic of converting a raw Yolov8 output tensor into detected objects:

```c
std::vector<YoloDet::Detection> YoloDet::detect(cv::Mat &mat) {
    static cv::Mat blob;
    static std::vector<cv::Mat> outputs;

    cv::dnn::blobFromImage(mat, blob, 1.0 / 255.0, modelShape, cv::Scalar(), true, false);
    net.setInput(blob);
    net.forward(outputs, net.getUnconnectedOutLayersNames());


    int rows = outputs[0].size[2];
    int dimensions = outputs[0].size[1];

    outputs[0] = outputs[0].reshape(1, dimensions);
    cv::transpose(outputs[0], outputs[0]);

    auto data = (float *) outputs[0].data;

    std::vector<int> class_ids{};
    std::vector<float> confidences{};
    std::vector<cv::Rect> boxes{};

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        float *classes_scores = data + 4;

        cv::Mat scores(1, classesCount, CV_32FC1, classes_scores);
        cv::Point class_id;
        double maxClassScore;

        minMaxLoc(scores, nullptr, &maxClassScore, nullptr, &class_id);

        if (maxClassScore > modelScoreThreshold) {
            confidences.push_back(float(maxClassScore));
            class_ids.push_back(class_id.x);

            float x = data[0];
            float y = data[1];
            float w = data[2];
            float h = data[3];

            int left = int((x - 0.5 * w) * x_factor);
            int top = int((y - 0.5 * h) * y_factor);

            int width = int(w * x_factor);
            int height = int(h * y_factor);

            boxes.emplace_back(left, top, width, height);
        }
        data += dimensions;
    }

    std::vector<int> nms_result;
    cv::dnn::NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, modelScoreThreshold, modelNMSThreshold, nms_result);

    std::vector<Detection> detections{};

    for (int idx: nms_result) {
        Detection result;
        result.class_id = class_ids[idx];
        result.confidence = confidences[idx];
        result.box = boxes[idx];
        detections.push_back(result);
    }

    return detections;
}
```

It utilizes `cv::dnn::NMSBoxes` under the hood. Note that the OpenCV DNN module is not always available by default.

2. An alternative to the custom scrip above, ONNXRuntime team has prepared an optimized Yolov8 detection model with NMS (non-maximum suppression) *built directly into the model* (via the ONNXRuntime-Extensions pack). You can find the model [here](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime-inference-examples/tree/main/mobile/examples/object_detection/android/app/src/main/res/raw) with a corresponding [Android example](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime-inference-examples/tree/main/mobile/examples/object_detection/android). With this approach, you won't even need to go down the rabbit hole trying to understand the Yolov8 output format, as the model outputs bounding boxes with scores from input images.

I haven't tested which one is faster but I presume ONNXRuntime + built-in NMS should yield better performance. Let me know if someone does the benchmark.

---

Note that Yolov8 has changed the output format, compared to previous generations (see [these lines](https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/blob/e5cb35edfc3bbc9d7d7db8a6042778a751f0e39e/examples/YOLOv8-CPP-Inference/inference.cpp#L31-L33)):

```
    // yolov5 has an output of shape (batchSize, 25200, 85) (Num classes + box[x,y,w,h] + confidence[c])
    // yolov8 has an output of shape (batchSize, 84,  8400) (Num classes + box[x,y,w,h])
```